# Dúvidas sobre OAuth e Tokens em uma API

Tags: api, laravel-5, restful, oauth2

Antes, gostaria de contextualizar meu cenário:

Sou um estudante na área que tem enorme paixão por desenvolvimento mobile e <strike>recentemente</strike> tenho visto a necessidade de **criar minhas próprias API's** para possibilitar a conversa entre o aplicativo e o meu banco de dados *(a.k.a. autenticação e criação de usuários, retorno, remoção, inserção e atualização de informações)*. Comecei a pesquisar e encontrei algumas boas frameworks, como Laravel, <strike>Lumen</strike>, Slim, outras... E mais um monte de palestras excelentes sobre escalabilidade e conceitos Restful.

Mas uma dúvida sempre esteve na minha cabeça, e está relacionada a maneira correta de se utilizar tokens no meu caso. Se a comunidade puder me ajudar, eu ficaria super grato.

1. O token do usuário deve ser atualizado cada vez que ele acessar a API? Se sim, qual é a questão que implica na obrigatoriedade desta função?
2. Ao receber uma requisição do usuário em uma rota **(e.g. api.awesome.com/user/12)** que irá retornar uma lista de informações deste e eu quero garantir que ele tenha acesso **APENAS** a lista dele, é melhor que eu busque no banco de dados **através do ID do usuário**, ou **através do token** passado no header? Ou em ambos? E se a resposta for **"através do token", como ficaria a questão Restful?** Como eu poderia passar **api.awesome.com/user/TOKEN_DO_USUARIO**? Não haveria problemas por ser uma url muito grande para ser trafegada?

Agora sobre a **validação de dados**:

1. É recomendável que eu nunca confie nos dados enviados pelo usuário, não é? Então como devo fazer a validação destes dados na API antes de inseri-los no banco de dados? *Verificar se é de fato um e-mail, um telefone celular, CEP, etc*. **Regex Pattern**? Existe alguma forma **menos trabalhosa** no **Laravel**? E em algum lugar <strike>não me pergunte onde</strike> li que **Regex não é uma maneira segura**. Isso é um fato? Por que?

Pequena dúvida sobre **CORS** *(confesso que não pesquisei a respeito, mas aproveitando essa publicação...)*

1. Qual é o problema de se utilizar *****? Sei que ele aceitará requisições de qualquer domínio mas, sabendo que quem enviará as requisições serão meus aplicativos e que nenhum deles possui um domínio *<strike>e, como sabemos, não posso me basear no IP do usuário para trabalhar no **CORS**</strike>*, qual é a alternativa correta?

Peço desculpas pelas dúvidas, mas adoraria se alguém pudesse me esclarecer essas questões.
Desde já, meu muito obrigado.

Comment: Olá, sugiro que você faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais a respeito do site. Sua pergunta é muito ampla, seria melhor fazer uma pergunta de cada vez ao invés de colocar varias em uma.

Comment: Eu acho que você tem diversas dúvidas, não uma. Pulverizar essas dúvidas aumentam as chances de obter resposta significativa, e também ajudam quem responde e só tem domínio parcial dos assuntos

Comment: Agradeço o comentário. Por mais que sejam várias perguntas, tenho a certeza de que qualquer usuário experiente na área conseguirá responder todas, já que as 4 perguntas são referentes ao mesmo assunto. No mais: Criar uma publicação pra cada questão não significaria um flood desnecessário? Já que todas as perguntas são respondidas com poucas linhas. Por isso julguei ser melhor centralizar todas.